# A set ISO8601 time to now-time

Tags: javascript, html, iso8601

I am trying to display sort of a "time since" counter on my website. The API call outputs like this. 
`"created_at": "2018-05-16T14:00:00Z",`

How would I go toward displaying the time since this time? This time is always set UTC time zone.

Preferably in a `hh:mm` format.

Appreciate all help.

Comment: You could use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: For parsing the date/time: [JavaScript: Which browsers support parsing of ISO-8601 Date String with Date.parse](//stackoverflow.com/q/5802461) For getting the difference: [How do I get the difference between two Dates in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41948)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple

```
var create_at = new Date("2018-05-16T14:00:00Z");
var current_time = new Date();
var elapsed_time = current_time - create_at;
```

elapsed_time is the time since create time in milliseconds. You can get seconds dividing it by 1000 like this.

```
var elapsed_seconds = elapsed_time / 1000;
```